# Launch Elevated CMD.exe from Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to launch an elevated CMD window from PowerShell but I am running into some issues. Below is the Code I have now.  There is an admin account on the machine that has the username of "test" and a Password of "test"

```
$username = "test"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "test" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
Start-Process "cmd.exe" -Credential $cred
```

This is all working fine for running an application from the user profile with no administrator rights that this script sits in, but when calling the cmd.exe it launches as expected with elevated rights but then immediately closes.

I have also tried calling it with the following:

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" -Credential $cred -ArgumentList '/k'
```

This also is not working.
I tested the elevated permissions by passing in an argument as follows and this works fine.

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" -Credential $cred -ArgumentList 'dir > dir.txt'
```

This will write out a dir.txt file to the C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 directory which is blocked on the user account but not for the administrator account test.

Any help on getting a persistent cmd window to show would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if you can start `cmd.exe` elevated without provoking the UAC prompt?

Comment: Unless run from an already-elevated console, the only way to create an elevated console is to use `-Verb RunAs`.
Irrespective of that, when run from an interactive console, `Start-Process cmd.exe` should start an interactive console that stays open (`/k` is only needed if you want to pass a command).
In short: I think we know what you want to do, but your symptoms are confusing - please add more diagnostic information to your question.
Please note that your script effectively gives administrative rights to anyone who runs it.

Comment: Agree; the question is not clear. I can run `Start-Process cmd.exe` and I get a cmd.exe window that does not close.

Comment: You could use [Psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062)

Comment: Use psexec to do what, precisely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Note: SomeShinyObject came up with the fundamentals of the approach in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268572/45375), but his parameter-passing technique is not robust (*update*: since corrected) - *do not use script blocks in lieu of strings* - see bottom.</sup>

- **`-Verb RunAs`** is what makes `Start-Process` **launch a process elevated**.
- However, **`-Verb RunAs` cannot be combined with the `-Credential` parameter**, so **you cannot directly control under what user account the elevation happens - but that is generally not necessary**:

  - If the current user is an administrator, elevation *invariably* happens in the context of that user, with the GUI prompt just asking for *confirmation*.
  - Otherwise, a GUI *dialog* is shown, asking for an administrator's username and password (with the username field blank).

**Security caveats**:

- Storing a password as plain text is a security risk in general.
- Additionally, **if you let *non-administrative* users execute the code below with stored admin credentials, you're effectively giving them administrative rights.**

If you still want to implement your script as specified, a **workaround** requires ***nesting* 2 `Start-Process` calls**:

- The 1st one runs an (invariably) non-elevated command *invisibly* in the context of the specified user - assumed to be an administrative user - using `-Credential`.

  - Since the specified user is an administrator, it's not a concern here, but if `-Credential` targets a non-admin user, it is advisable to also specify a `-WorkingDir` argument that the specified user is known to have permissions to access - otherwise, the call may fail (the current location is retained, and the target user may not be allowed to access it).
- The 2nd one, embedded in the 1st, then uses `-Verb RunAs` to run the target command *elevated*, which then happens *in the context of the specified user*.

  - Note: **Even with a credentials object that includes the password, you will still get the yes/no UAC prompt to confirm the intent to elevate** - unless UAC has been turned off (which is not advisable).
  - The working directory will invariably be `$env:SYSTEMROOT\System32`; `-Verb RunAs` ignores even a `-WorkingDirectory` value; if you want to change to a specific directory, embed a `cd` command in the command passed to `cmd.exe`; the bottom section of [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542575/45375) shows this technique with a `powershell.exe` / `Set-Location` call.

This command does exactly what you asked for - **please note the security caveat**:

```
# Construct the credentials object
$username = "jdoe"
# CAVEAT: Storing a password as plain text is a security risk in general.
#         Additionally, if you let non-administrative users execute this 
#         code with a stored password, you're effectively giving them
#         administrative rights.
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "test" -AsPlainText -Force    
$cred = New-Object PSCredential -Args $username, $password

# Start an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) as user $username.
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -WindowStyle Hidden `
 '-noprofile -command "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs"'
```

Note that the embedded, 2nd command is passed as a *single string* to the (implied) `-ArgumentList` (a.k.a. `-Args`) parameter.

In this simple case, with only 1 level of embedded quoting - the `"` instances inside the `'...'` string - and no need for expansions (string interpolation), passing a single string is a viable option, but with more sophisticated commands quoting gets tricky.

**`-ArgumentList` is defined as type `[string[]]`**, i.e., an *array* of string arguments. **If you pass *multiple*, `,`-separated arguments, it is PowerShell that synthesizes the command line for you**:

- **Caveat**: A [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately requires that argument with *embedded spaces* be enclosed in *embedded double-quoting* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375) for details.

The following command demonstrates this technique: It is a variant that passes a command for `cmd.exe` to execute through, and uses a variable reference in that command:

```
$msg = 'This is an elevated Command Prompt.'

Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -WindowStyle Hidden -Args `
 '-noprofile', '-command', "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -Args /k, echo, '$msg'"
```

The `cmd.exe` command that is ultimately executed (with elevation) is:
`cmd /k echo This is an elevated Command Prompt.`

---

#### Optional Reading: Why using *script blocks* in lieu of strings is ill-advised

**tl;dr**

- *Do not get into the habit of using script blocks where strings are expected. While convenient, it is not robust, and remembering when and why it will fail is nontrivial.*

At first glance, script blocks (`{ ... }`) seem like a convenient option:

```
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList { /k echo hi! }
```

The above executes `cmd /k echo hi!` in a new console window, as expected.
The syntax is convenient, because the `{ ... }` seemingly provide a context in which quoting is easy: you're free to use *embedded* `"` and `'` instances to construct your command line.

However, what happens behind the scenes is that a script block is converted to a *string*, because that's the type of argument(s) `-ArgumentList` expects, and **when a script block is converted to a *string*, its *literal* contents - everything between `{` and `}` - is used**.
*This means that no string interpolation takes place, so you cannot use variables or subexpressions.*

Take this attempt to pass a command based on a variable:

```
 Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList { /k echo Honey, I`'m $HOME! }
```

What this will execute is: `cmd /k echo Honey, I'm $HOME!` - *`$HOME` was not expanded.*

By contrast, passing either an interpolated string or the arguments individually works as intended:

```
# As a single string (argument list):
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/k echo Honey, I'm $HOME!"

# As an array of arguments:
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList /k, echo, "Honey, I'm $HOME!"
```

`$HOME` is expanded (interpolated) in both cases, and something like
`cmd /k echo Honey, I'm C:\Users\jdoe` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to double up your `Start-Process` first with a `-Credential` parameter with your admin credentials and then with a `-Verb runas` on your second `Start-Process`. After that it gets a little complicated with quoting for CMD.exe.

Overall, it should look something like this.

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList {-noexit -noprofile -Command "Start-Process powershell -argumentlist {-command cmd.exe -args \"/K #yourcommands# \"}" -verb runas} -Credential $Cred
```

**So scratch this. Read mklement0's answer as to why**

There's always opportunity to learn more and I didn't know wrapping an `ArgumentList` in a `ScriptBlock` prevented variable expansion. So...don't do that.

The method stays the same, though. You'll still need two `Start-Process` calls, just now you have to get the quoting right.

```
#Both of these work
Start-Process powershell -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "-noprofile", "-command", "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList /k, echo, 'something'"
# $Something will expand into it's value rather than literally
Start-Process powershell -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "-noprofile", "-command", "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList /k, echo, '$something'"
```