# Trying to run a PowerShell script with admin rights by a user that doesnt have admin rights and the admin credentials are in the script

Tags: powershell, administrator

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script that requires admin rights and the user I'm logged in as doesn't have admin rights. I have no problem temporarily storing the admin credentials on in the script or somewhere else on the computer. I know this is a security issue but Im testing a solution. Below is the code but it errors out with a weird error that doesn't make any sense to me.

`Start-Process powershell -Credential (Get-Credential) -ArgumentList "-file C:\test.ps1"`

Comment: Please show us the "weird error that doesn't make any sense [...]"!

Comment: I think the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281908/45375) explains the problem and offers a solution; let us know if it doesn't.

Comment: Im not sure how to test. How would i test including my ps1 script? Not sure how to write it syntactically?