# Start-Process -Credential silently fails in windows-startup-script-ps1

Tags: windows, powershell, google-cloud-platform, active-directory, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to automate setting up ADFS on GCP. In order to do this, I'm trying to create a service user prior to installing ADFS using `New-ADuser`. I want to do this in `windows-startup-script-ps1`. However, since the account that script runs as doesn't have permission to do this, I need to switch to the delegated administrator account. When I try to do this with `Start-Process`, it doesn't give any output and it doesn't actually run the command. Here's a simplified example with `echo` and `Out-File` instead of `New-ADuser`.

```
# Copyright 2024 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString '[redacted]' -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'adfs\setupadmin', $Password
Start-Process powershell '-NoProfile', '-Command', {echo 'it works' | Out-File test.txt} -Credential $Credential -Wait

Write-Output 'test.txt:'
Get-Content test.txt
```

This gives an error:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\test.txt' because it does not exist
```

If I remove `-Credential $Credential`, it runs, but it will fail with a permission error if I try to do `New-ADuser`. On the other hand, if I RDP into the instance after it's created and run Powershell as admin, `Start-Process` with `-Credential` works fine. Why doesn't it work in `windows-startup-script-ps1`? Is there a workaround?

I also tried providing the full path to `powershell.exe` with the same results.

Update: I tried using `gcloud compute ssh` instead of the startup script (which would have been an acceptable workaround), and found that it fails there, too (same behavior). From my research, it looks like `Start-Process -Credential` may not work in session 0.

Comment: Are you sure the file is created in the `C:\Windows\system32\` path?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I just tried changing the path to `C:\Users\setupadmin\test.txt` in both locations with the same results. I've also tried a number of other methods to check whether the Powershell invocation was working, such as `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError` (gives empty files, but works via RDP) and running `Get-ADUser -Filter *` when trying the actual `Add-ADuser` (again, shows that it works over RDP). I wonder if it has something to do with `Start-Process -Credential` trying to open a new window.

Comment: Even if you pass an administrator's credentials to `Start-Process -Credential`, the resulting process will _not_ be elevated - so it is to be expected that you can't create files in `C:\Windows\system32\test.txt` (though I'd expect an access-denied error). If you want to run as a different user _and_ with elevation, you need to _nest_ two `Start-Process` calls, with the inner one using `-Verb RunAs`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281908/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 The original process started by using `windows-startup-script-ps1` is elevated and can create files in `C:\Windows\system32\ ` (yes, I've tried it). Besides, see my last comment, where it also failed to do a number of other things that don't require admin privileges. I also tried the two nested `Start-Process` calls trick using `-Verb RunAs`. Nothing works.

Comment: @mklement0 My goal in using `-Credentials` isn't to get local admin privileges on the computer (`windows-startup-script-ps1` already runs with that), it's to be an admin of the Active Directory domain so I can run `New-ADuser`.

Comment: Understood, @BrianMcCutchon, but note that (at least in local invocations) it doesn't matter whether your calling process is elevated or not: the process launched via `-Credential` is invariably _non-elevated_. The nested approach usually works, and I have no explanation for your symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This post doesn't offer a *solution*, but merely *pinpoints the problem*, building on your own observation:

- Seemingly, your code runs in the `services` session (window station), i.e. in the *invisible* session with ID `0` in which Windows services runs.
- De facto, attempts to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) from this session with `-Credential`, i.e. to run *with a different user identity*, FAIL, even when the caller runs *with elevation* (which is typical in that session).

  - It is not obvious from the *privileges* of the caller what the problem is: `whoami /all` reveals the following in *both* an elevated *interactive* session - where the command *succeeds* - and in a session `0` process - where the command *fails*:

    - `SeImpersonatePrivilege` is `Enabled`
    - `SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege` is `Disabled`
- In a failing call from session `0`, the process exit code reported by the process that `Start-Process -Credential` creates is (obtained via `(Start-Process ... -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode`):

  - `-1073741502`, which implies the following, generic error: [`ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED` -

    A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.](https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_NT/0xC0000142)